# Determining age of a file in shell script

Tags: unix, shell, file

G'day,

I need to see if a specific file is more than 58 minutes old from a sh shell script. I'm talking straight vanilla Solaris shell with some POSIX extensions it seems.

I've thought of doing a

```
touch -t YYYYMMDDHHmm.SS /var/tmp/toto
```

where the timestamp is 58 minutes ago and then doing a

```
find ./logs_dir \! -newer /var/tmp/toto -print
```

We need to postprocess some log files that have been retrieved from various servers using mirror. Waiting for the files to be stable is the way this team decides if the mirror is finished and hence that day's logs are now complete and ready for processing.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

cheers,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use different units in the find command, for example:

```
find . -mtime +0h55m
```

Will return any files with modified dates older than 55 minutes ago.

Comment: find has a -mmin predicate, eg. -mmin +58

Comment: That depends on the version of find. Maybe you can do that in a really new version, or maybe Mac or something, but the GNU Find 4.2 on most of my Linux boxes takes "-mtime" to be increments of 24 hours.

Comment: Where does this work? On mine (`find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0`), I try this and get `find: invalid argument `+0h55m' to `-mtime'`.

Answer (score 22):

I needed something to test age of a specific file, to not re-download too often.  So using `GNU date` and `bash`:

```
# if file's modtime hour is less than current hour:
[[ $(date +%k -r GPW/mstall.zip) -lt $(date +%k) ]] && \
wget -S -N \
http://bossa.pl/pub/metastock/mstock/mstall.zip \
```

Update--this version works much better for me, and is more accurate and understandable:

```
[[ $(date +%s -r mstall.zip) -lt $(date +%s --date="77 min ago") ]] && echo File is older than 1hr 17min
```

The BSD variant (tested on a Mac) is:

```
[[ $(stat -f "%m" mstall.zip) -lt $(date -j -v-77M +%s) ]] && echo File is older than 1hr 17min
```

Comment: The second version is a really elegant (and clear) use of the date(1) command, nice code!

Comment: `--date` can be abbreviated to `-d` for brevity though. (Requires everyone to know what `-d` is. Here everyone does.)

Answer (score 5):

This is now an old question, sorry, but for the sake of others searching for a good solution as I was...

The best method I can think of is to use the [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command which is the only Un*x command I know of that can directly test file age:

```
if [ "$(find $file -mmin +58)" != "" ]
then
  ... regenerate the file ...
fi
```

The other option is to use the [stat(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) command to return the age of the file in seconds and the date command to return the time now in seconds.  Combined with the bash shell math operator working out the age of the file becomes quite easy:

```
age=$(stat -c %Y $file)
now=$(date +"%s")
if (( (now - age) > (58 * 60) ))
then
    ... regenerate the file ...
fi
```

You could do the above without the two variables, but they make things clearer, as does use of bash math (which could also be replaced).  I've used the find(1) method quite extensively in scripts over the years and recommend it unless you actually need to know age in seconds.

Comment: The date -r usage in @Marcos answer above is also very nice, I had missed it the first time I read this.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen : This is GNU `stat` (from the GNU `coreutils` package) which you can install on Mac (e.g. using `brew`) as well.  As for the option: `-c` is equivalent to `--format` it must be followed by the wanted format argument, in this case, `%Y` is the format for time of last data modification, (seconds since Epoch). Official docs can be found at:  http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/stat (or `man stat`)

Answer (score 4):

A piece of the puzzle might be using `stat`. You can pass `-r` or `-s` to get a parseable representation of all file metadata.

```
find . -print -exec stat -r '{}' \;
```

AFAICR, the 10th column will show the mtime.

Comment: I don't see `stat(1)` dictated by POSIX/SUS, but BSD definitely has it.  Not all the same option switches as GNU, but that's unsurprising.

Comment: Column 9 on Mac OS X. You can confirm this by doing stat -s on your file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking to test the time of a *specific* file you can start by using `test` and comparing it to your specially created file:

```
test /path/to/file -nt /var/tmp/toto
```

or:

```
touch -t YYYYMMDDHHmm.SS /var/tmp/toto
if [/path/to/file -nt /var/tmp/toto]
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ls and awk to get what you need as well. Awk has a c-ish printf that will allow you to format the columns any way you want.

I tested this in bash on linux and ksh on solaris.

Fiddle with options to get the best values for your application. Especially "--full-time" in bash and "-E" in ksh.

### bash

`ls -l foo | awk '{printf "%3s %1s\n", $6, $7}'`

2011-04-19 11:37

`ls --full-time foo | awk '{printf "%3s %1s\n", $6, $7}'`

2011-04-19 11:37:51.211982332

### ksh

`ls -l bar | awk '{printf "%3s %1s %s\n", $6, $7, $8}'`

May 3 11:19

`ls -E bar | awk '{printf "%3s %1s %s\n", $6, $7, $8}'`

2011-05-03 11:19:23.723044000 -0400