# Shell script - Search through all files?

Tags: file

I am trying to write a shell script that will search for a file name (given as an argument) and if the file was modified less than or equal to 10 minutes ago, exit 0, if it was modified more than 10 minutes ago exit 1, and if the file doesn't exist exit 2.

Here's my code:

```
if find $1
then
        if find $1 -mmin -11
        then
                echo "Exit 0"
        else
                echo "Exit 1"
        fi
else
        echo "Exit 2"
fi
```

How do I make this search through ALL files on the system?

Also, if the file exists then check if it was modified within the past 10 minutes, if it was then exit 1. If the file doesn't exist then exit 2. I have used echo "" so that I can see which exit happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969407/determining-age-of-a-file-in-shell-script will help with the file time issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ -n $1 ]]; then 
  find / -name $1 -mmtime -10 2>/dev/null
  if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then 
    exit 0
  else
    exit 1
  fi
else
 ...
```

Comment: There is no need for the if; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi check.  Make find the last command, and the shell script will exit with the value returned by find.  However, find will succeed even if it doesn't find the file, so using the return value of find is not helpful.

Comment: I threw that in there because of his echo calls. But yeah find returns 0 on success and non 0 for errors/not found.

Comment: Which version of find?  Possibly gnu find behaves that way, but it is non-standard.  (As is the option -mmtime; probably you mean -mtime).

Comment: Just checked gnu find: it succeeds (returns 0) even if -name or -mtime find no files.

Comment: My mistake then u could use a pipe to grep  and the return vale of that to verify returns.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do if there are two files of that name found on the filesystem?  (For the moment, I'll assume that is not an issue and only work with the first file found.)  Your question contradicts itself: in the preamble you say you want to exit with 0 if it has been modified in the last 10 minutes, but later you say that a recent modification should trigger an exit of 1.  The following solution returns 0 of the file has NOT been modified in the last 10 minutes.  This requires the gnu extension to date that gives the %s format specifier.

```
#!/bin/sh

fullpath=$( find / -name ${1?No file specified} | sed 1q | grep . ) || exit 2
test $( expr $( date +%s ) - $( stat -c %Y $fullpath )) -gt 600
```