# Determining age of a file in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to determine age of a file in R. Here is a link that I found:
[Determining age of a file in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969407/determining-age-of-a-file-in-shell-script)

I'm wondering is there any native R way to determine the age of a file in days unit(or hours). 
Thank you for reading this.

Update (I think this is working):

```
ageoffile <- function(x,unit="sec"){
  dt = .Internal(Sys.time())-.Internal(file.info(x))$mtime
  if(unit=="hours")
    return(dt/3600)
  else if(unit=="days")
    return(dt/(3600*24))
  else return(dt)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the information about your file using the **file.info()** function, and the current date and time using **Sys.time()**

```
info <- file.info("PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE")
Sys.time() - info$mtime
```

For instance:

```
> system("touch temp")
> info <- file.info("temp")
> Sys.time() - info$mtime
Time difference of 5.23292 secs
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I'm looking for a comparable value to sort the age of files.
thanks

Comment: Actualy Sys.time and info$mtime return DateTimeClasses objects. It means that you do not have to care about the unit. R will handle all conversion for you when you do operations, comparisons or sorting etc. In short the values are already comparable.